# Script to Rename Folder in Network Share As a different user with PIV Card

Tags: powershell

Okay, so I'm trying to make this simple stupid easy for people, as well as myself - I'm trying to basically rename a name folder inside a network share but the way we are set up is to have 2 accounts, your main account and one with Admin access. We can ONLY log in with PIV(CAC/Smart) cards, password is not an option.

Basically, trying to run a script as a different user that prompts for the folder name to rename and rename to .old.

Here's what I have that works in PowerShell, but involves manually renaming everything.

```
Rename-Item "\\%%SERVERNAMEHERE%%\PROFILE\%%NAMEHERE%%" "\\%%SERVERNAMEHERE\PROFILE\%%NAMEHERE%%old"
```

I understand this is very basic but I'm still pretty novice in scripting.

Comment: Just run powershell as a different user? If you're using a CAC with a PIV cert, AD is using that very for authentication; using Kerberos. So it'll pass ur creds.

Comment: One point in your code is that PowerShell does not use `%variablename%` for environment variable names; it uses `$env:variablename` instead. But in any case, since you are a scripting novice, I would recommend finding a GUI tool that can perform batch renaming for you.

Comment: I guess I didn't pose my question right - I want a script to pop up a window to insert the name of the user to rename. I can use the powershell as another user just fine, it's getting people who are not tech savy to do it with just a name. Right now I have 3 people avoiding these tickets because "It's too complicated". 

Right now, I already run the powershell myself but I have to manually do it, having a pop up to change would change my life.

Comment: What if your script prompts inside the PowerShell window for the username? Would that work?

Comment: That'd be perfect. As long as I can teach someone just to type a name somewhere, I'm kosher.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short script that prompts for a user name and runs `Rename-Item`. You should be able to adapt to your needs fairly easily.

```
$UserName = Read-Host "Enter username [blank=quit]"
if ( $UserName -ne "" ) {
  Rename-Item "\\servername\PROFILE\$UserName" "$UserName.old"
  Read-Host "Press ENTER to continue"
}
```